# Android facebook share play store link with text does show text

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I want to show content as text and bellow the app link . But when i tried with

```
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("How to share content")
                    //.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.numetriclabz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/114.png"))
                    .setContentDescription("simple LinkedIn integration")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=arifhansat.android.firebase.dailyhadish"))

                    .build();
            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

This only post the app link not text but when i change the play store link as other site link then it works fine .
What the problem with play store link ?

Comment: It will use the OG tags on the link your share

Comment: Pretty sure that the limitations described here apply to other forms of sharing as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params